# Мне нужен код который будет брать с ImageView картинку и записывать ее в файл внутреннего хранилища

Tags: android, android-imageview

Пожалуйста напишите мне этот код. Буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы вытащить картинку можно использовать такой способ:

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm=imageView.getDrawingCache();
```

дальше сохраняем ее:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), yourBitmap, yourTitle , yourDescription);
```

так же не забудьте добавить разрешение в манифест:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Вот есть еще [такой способ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718374/save-image-from-imageview-to-device-gallery).

P.S. то что код нужен это конечно хорошо, но все-таки не мешает и показывать то что вы сами нашли по данному вопросу. Вот есть [туториал](https://lmgtfy.com/?q=get%20image%20from%20imageview%20android%20and%20save%20it).

Comment: И куда она сохраняется?) В галерее нету картинки, которую я установил в ImageView

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media

Comment: У меня маленький вопросик не по теме, как сделать так, чтобы код запускался 1 раз в неделю?

Comment: планировщиком как-то можно я думаю, ставите задачу и ставите фоновый сервис который будет стартовать раз в неделю